# Output and save results of a nested loop in R

Tags: r, loops, nested, save, output

I am using the script below to loop over the data `w` three times and it outputs three results when I use the print to display them. I am trying to output the results to an assigned variable `my_vector(j)` but only the last iteration results are displayed. How can I save the results for each iteration in an array?

```
DU<-c(70,85,95)
a<-1-sqrt(3)*((100-DU)/130)
     
my_vector = c()
w<-c(0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5)
w_i<-1/w
for (i in 1:length(DU)){
  for (j in 1:length(w)){
   if (w_i[j] > 2-a[i]) {
       E[j]<-1
    } else if (w_i[j]<2-a[i]) {
       E[j]<-((a[i]*w[j]+1)^2-4*w[j])/(4*(a[i]-1)*w[j]^2)
    } else {
       E[j]=w_i[j]
    }
    my_vector[j]<-(E[j])
    print(E[j])
  }
  my_vector[j]<-(E[j])
 }
```

Comment: You need to declare `E` as well, eg `E = c()` before starting the loop.

Comment: Thank you. I noted that and corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you call `my_vector[j]<-(E[j])`, `j` only takes values between 1 and `length(w)`, so for each iteration of the loop `i` you rewrite everything (each time you change of value for `i` then `j` restarts to 1).

Replace by:

```
my_vector[j + length(w)*(i-1)]<-(E[j])
```

Also, I think that you should remove the last line with

```
my_vector[j]<-(E[j])
```

As it is outside of the loop on `j` (or at least I don't understand why it is here)

Comment: Thanks for response. But this solution gives an output vector of length 33 instead of 3 by 11. I need the output as a 3 by 11. For each loop in own column/row.

Comment: SO you want an array with 3 columns and 11 rows? You an either convert the my_vector into a matrix or declare a matrix (mat = matrixNA, nrow = ..., ncol = ...) before the loop and fill it in the loop with mat[i,j] = E[j]

Comment: Thanks again. It works. I used dim(my_vector) <- c(11, 3) also.